# FormData doesn't include the button Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm having a problem with `FormData`, it was working a couple days ago but now it doesn't work, it submits all the inputs except the submit button. Here's my login form.

```
<form action="" method="post" name="login_user">
    <label for="username">Username/e-mail <span class="error" id="user-error"></span></label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required>
    <br>
    <label for="passwd">Password <span class="error" id="passwd-error"></span></label>
    <input type="password" name="passwd" id="passwd" required>
    <br>
    <p><input type="checkbox" checked name="remember"> Remember me <span class="forgot"><a href="<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>/reset">Forgotten password</a></span> </p>
    <input type="submit" id="login" value="Login" name="login">
    <p>Don't have an account? <a href="<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>/register/">Sign up</a></p>
</form>
```

JS for login, uses MVC.

```
//ajax login
var login = document.forms.namedItem('login_user');
if (login) {
    login.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        if (validatePassword('passwd', 'passwd-error')) {
            var data = new FormData(login);
            var userlogin = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var btn = document.getElementById('login');
            btn.value = 'Login, Please wait...';

            userlogin.open('POST', url + 'login/login_user_ajax', true);
            userlogin.onload = function (event) {
                if (userlogin.status == 200) {
                    var result = JSON.parse(userlogin.responseText);
                    if (result.results == 'success.') {
                        alert('logged in'); //change this later
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById('cred-error').innerHTML = result.results;
                    }
                    btn.value = 'Login';
                }
            };
            userlogin.send(data);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
```

The login method in my controller, the button is not detected.

```
public function login_user_ajax() {
    $this->login_user(1);
}

private function login_user($ajax  = '')
{
    if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'login')) {
        $new_user = $this->model('User');
        $new_user->setDb(Controller::getDb());
        $new_user->set_site(SITE_URL);
        $user = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
        $passwd = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'passwd', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
        if ($new_user->login($user, $passwd)) {
            if ($ajax) {
                $site_data['results'] = 'success.';
                echo json_encode($site_data);
                return true;
            }else {
                $this->redirect(SITE_URL . '/edit');
            }
        } else {
            if (!$ajax){
            return 'The username or password is incorrect.';
            }else {
                $site_data['results'] = 'The username or password is incorrect.';
                echo json_encode($site_data);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }else {
        print_r($_POST);
    }
}
```

I get this when I `print_r` `$_POST`, with no button.

[image]

Comment: That's how it's supposed to work, the submit button isn't submitted?

Comment: @adeneo but it was working.

Comment: @adeneo: With a normal form submission, the submit button's name and value are sent with the form if that button was used to cause the submission. So for instance, if you have a form with four different submit buttons, all with the name `btn`, and each with a different value, if you use a button to submit the form, the data will have `btn=the-value-of-the-clicked-button` in it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - good point, I should probably have noted that when using `formData`, it's not submitted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're not actually using the default submit (instead you're doing ajax), you need to add the clicked button yourself. One easy way to do this is to add a hidden input to your form with the name you want the button to have, and then have all the buttons in the form use this click handler:

```
function clickHandler() {
    this.form.theHiddenInput.value = this.value;
}
```

That way, *if* a button was used to submit the form, the button's handler sets the value of the hidden input prior to the `submit`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my SwitchToggle component that I built with a `<button>` element. Even if the element had a `name` it wasn't included in my `FormData` when submitting the form.

I ended up adding a visually hidden `<input type="checkbox">` in the markup with the same `name` and `value` property as the SwitchToggle component. This input does nothing (it is not clickable and not visual) except showing up in `FormData`. This example is in React but the approach is applicable to all frameworks or vanilla JavaScript.

```
const SwitchToggle = (props) => {
  const { id, name, className } = props;
  const [enabled, setIsEnabled] = React.useState(props.enabled);

  return (
    <>
      <input
        style={{opacity: 0.05}}
        name={name}
        checked={enabled}
        type={"checkbox"}
      />
      <button
        className={`switch-toggle ${enabled ? 'on' : 'off'}`}
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          setIsEnabled(!enabled);
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

[Full example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/calsal/pen/ExPRWLO?editors=0110).

Since my component is On/Off I used a checkbox input but you might as well use a text input with a string value.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled upon this and came up with a very elegant solution for my situation:

```js
// ...
const form = document.querySelector("#form");
form.addEventListener("submit", event => {
    const formData = new FormData(form);
    if (event.submitter && event.submitter.getAttribute("name")) {
        formData.append(form.submitter.getAttribute("name"), form.submitter.getAttribute("value"));
    }
    // do your fetch ...
});
```