# PHP sends back empty body

Tags: php, http, post, vue.js, forms

I'm trying to send form data from Vue Resource to my PHP page. I can see it displayed on the PHP page but when I send it back as JSON I get an empty response. Why is it sending an empty response?

#### Edit:

It looks like the problem is that the value for the submit button is not set in PHP. I am not sure why that is happening. Tried using `$_REQUEST` and `axios/$.post` but it makes no difference.

#### PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']){
   echo json_encode($_POST);
}
```

#### JS:

```
this.$http.post('addalbum.php', new FormData($('#submitalbum')))
.then(data => console.log(data));
```

#### HTML:

```
<form class="col s12" id="submitalbum" method="post" action="addalbum.php">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
            <input  name="artist" placeholder="Artist" type="text">

        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
            <input  name="title" placeholder="Title" type="text">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input  name="genre" placeholder="Genre">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input  id="released" type="number" name="released" placeholder="Year Released">
        </div>
        <button @click.prevent="addNewAlbum" name="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Where are you "sending it back" in the code above?

Comment: Using the echo statement. It works fine if it's anything other than the $_POST array.

Comment: PHP is insane, I'll go away, sorry for poking my head in...

Comment: Show us your `#submitalbum` form

Comment: Updated my post.

Comment: Ok, since the output is empty, it means that the check for `$_POST['submit']` existence has failed. Try to change the submit button to `<input @click.prevent="addNewAlbum" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn" >`

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The empty response is returned for multiple reasons. See them explained below.

#### jQuery selector

It appears that the selector for finding the form uses the jQuery id selector:

```
this.$http.post('addalbum.php', new FormData($('#submitalbum')))
```

But [the jQuery function](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/) (i.e. [$()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/)) returns a collection (an array):

```js
var submitAlbumCollection = $('#submitalbum');
console.log('submitAlbumCollection: ', submitAlbumCollection);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="col s12" id="submitalbum" method="post" action="addalbum.php"></form>
```

However [FormData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) needs "*An HTML [`<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) element*"<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)</sup>, not an array.

So if you are going to use the jQuery function, take the first element from it to get the reference to the form:

```
var forms = $('#submitalbum');
if (forms.length) {
    this.$http.post('addalbum.php', new FormData(forms[0]))
```

#### button elements don't send value

A `<button>` is not a form input and hence there would not be a corresponding value in the form data. This if you want to check for form values, try checking for the artist, title, etc.

```
if(isset($_POST['artist'])) {
    echo json_encode($_POST);
}
```

If you really wanted to check if `$_POST['submit']` is truthy, you could:

- add a hidden input:

  ```
  <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="1">
  ```
- convert the button to a submit button

  ```
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="1">
  ```
- take the suggestion from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40202205/1575353) and manually [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) an entry to the form data

See a demonstration in [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/87nj-xd5k). Note that phpfiddle doesn't allow multiple pages so the code from *addalbum.php* was placed at the top, and references to it were replaced with `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>` (i.e. in the client-side code).

#### Missing parenthesis

Additionally, there is a missing parenthesis on the first line of the PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']){
```

To correct this, add the missing closing parenthesis to close the expression:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData</sub>